# Comprehend parallel programming

Tags: parallel-computing

I'm asking the question on the behalf of my classmates. We have a trouble about parallel programming that we can't comprehend threads, semaphores, forks and etc. We have been taking third time the course called as system programming. The instructor of the course goes with Unix, C and POSIX standarts. There are some books like robbins concurrent programming(our course book), the linux programming interface. But, because of our lecturer explanation we can't understand usages  and benefits of parallel programming. If there was a chance to only study the course in a semester maybe we can accomplish some logics and ideas, but no.Even so, now he has given an assignment, we are on semaphores, threads and syncronazation and don't get anything about them. What can we do? How can we comprehend the logic of parallel programming and usages(how to use) of it?

Comment: It's hard to provide a suggestion for a "I can't understand X" type of question. Try going in a library, quickly browse all related books on parallel programming, and see if some of those are accessible to you. Read about standard problems/techniques (reader/writers, producers/consumers, dining philosphers, ...) and try to re-create their solutions using semaphores or some other mechanism.

Comment: Anyway, it is a bit weird if you can't perceive the "benefits of parallel programming". Nowadays computers are getting more and more parallel, instead of faster and faster. Network servers have to interact with many clients at the same time. It is very important to understand what the issues in such settings are, and what solutions are known.